# multiple UIswitches one randomize button

Tags: ios, swift, uiswitch

I recently started learning Swift which is my first attempt to learning how to program and I started my first app. I used several tutorials and so far I could solve every problem through research. Now I am stuck.

I want to create an app that can pick a random cocktail for me out of an array (cocktails) based on filters. To do so, I created 21 filters (`cocktail.filter({!$o.orangeJuice})` for example. This takes all cocktails out of the array using orange juice.).

Creating the UI I added 21 UISwitches to toggle whether a filter has to be applied or not.

My randomize button works and there is a random cocktail name displayed but I can't get those UISwitches to work.

See my code:

```
var cocktailNoOrangeJuice = cocktails.filter({!$0.orangeJuice})
var cocktailNoLemonJuice = cocktails.filter({!$0.lemonJuice})
var cocktailNoAppleJuice = cocktails.filter({!$0.appleJuice})
var cocktailNoMaraJuice = cocktails.filter({!$0.maraJuice})
var cocktailNoLimeJuice = cocktails.filter({!$0.limeJuice})
var cocktailNoBananaJuice = cocktails.filter({!$0.bananaJuice})
var cocktailNoPeachJuice = cocktails.filter({!$0.peachJuice})
var cocktailNoCherryJuice = cocktails.filter({!$0.cherryJuice})
var cocktailNoJohanJuice = cocktails.filter({!$0.johanJuice})
var cocktailNoMangoJuice = cocktails.filter({!$0.mangoJuice})
var cocktailNoGrapefJuice = cocktails.filter({!$0.grapefJuice})
var cocktailNoTomatoJuice = cocktails.filter({!$0.tomatoJuice})
var cocktailNoCranbJuice = cocktails.filter({!$0.cranbJuice})
var cocktailNoBloodJuice = cocktails.filter({!$0.bloodJuice})
var cocktailNoPineapJuice = cocktails.filter({!$0.pineapJuice})
var cocktailNoCola = cocktails.filter({!$0.cola})
var cocktailNoSprite = cocktails.filter({!$0.sprite})
var cocktailNoBitter = cocktails.filter({!$0.bitter})
var cocktailNoTonic = cocktails.filter({!$0.tonic})
var cocktailNoGinger = cocktails.filter({!$0.ginger})
var cocktailNoAlc = cocktails.filter({!$0.noalc})

//this is a new array currently with the "noalc"-filter applied
var cocktailfiltered = cocktails.filter({!$0.noalc})


class ViewController: UIViewController {
  // this is one of the UISwitches 
@IBOutlet weak var lemon: UISwitch!


// The label for Cocktail output and the random button
@IBOutlet weak var ergebnis: UILabel!
@IBAction func random(sender: AnyObject) {

    let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(cocktailfiltered.count)))

  ergebnis.text = (cocktailfiltered[randomIndex].name)
    }
}
```

Please forgive me if this too silly. I found out how to pick up the state of a `UISwitch` (e.g lemon.on ...) but cannot use this information to apply a filter.

Any help is highly appreciated. Though I first hoped to be able to solve this on my own now it gets frustrating.
Notice that the cocktails are defined as members of a class and every ingredient such as orange juice throws a bool. Thus the filters are manually working. But not in the UI.

Edit: So this is the version right now. In my opinion it looks far better thanks to @vadian but causes my app to crash.

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
let keys = ["lemonJuice", "limeJuice", "bananaJuice", "pineapJuice", "maraJuice", "mangoJuice", "orangeJuice", "appleJuice", "peachJuice", "bloodJuice", "grapefJuice", "tomatoJuice", "cranbJuice", "cherryJuice", "johanJuice", "cola", "sprite", "bitter", "tonic", "ginger", "noalc"]
var states = [true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true]

@IBAction func changeState(sender: UISwitch) {
    let index = sender.tag
    states[index] = sender.on}

@IBOutlet weak var ergebnis: UILabel!
@IBAction func random(sender: AnyObject) {

    var conditions = [String]()
    for (index, state) in states.enumerate() {
        if state {
            conditions.append("(\(keys[index]) == TRUE)")
        }
    }
    let format = conditions.joinWithSeparator(" AND ")
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format:format)

    let filtered = (cocktails as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(predicate)
    let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(filtered.count)))

  ergebnis.text = (filtered[randomIndex].name)
    }
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Suggestion:

1. Create two arrays, one for the names/keys of the `Bool` properties in your custom class

   ```
   let keys = ["orangeJuice", "lemonJuice" ... ]
   ```

   and one for the states of the corresponding switches

   ```
   var states = [false, false, ...]
   ```
2. Assign tags to the `UISwitch`es starting with zero in order of the keys array.
3. Create a change state `IBAction` and assign the action to all `UISwitch`es

   ```
   @IBAction func changeState(sender: UISwitch) {
     let index = sender.tag
     states[index] = sender.on
   }
   ```
4. in the `random` function create an `NSPredicate` programmatically by a repeat loop to get all `true` values of the `states` array and the corresponding key of the `keys` array. Then filter the cocktail array by that predicate and get the random cocktail.

PS: For a good user experience get the filtered cocktails in the `changeState` function and inform the user in case no cocktail matches the chosen ingredients.

Update:

An example to create the predicate

```
var conditions = [String]()
for (index, state) in states.enumerate() {
  if state {
     conditions.append("(\(keys[index]) == TRUE)")
  }
}
let format = conditions.joinWithSeparator(" AND ")
let predicate = NSPredicate(format:format)
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @vadian! I am trying to understand what you said there. Step 4 is the one I don't get so far. Plus: I forgot to mention that the UISwitches are on by default. That should actually inform the user that when the switch is checked off, the corresponding filter is applied. Does that make a difference?

Comment: No, but if the switches are on by default set all values of `states` to `true`

Comment: sorry I did not even make it to step 3 this is embarrasing. I created the two arrays and then tried to assign a tag to the first switch. `@IBOutlet weak var lemon: UISwitch!` `lemon.tag=0`. that did not work

Comment: You have to assign the tags in Interface Builder

Comment: I created both arrays and the outlets inside the ViewControler class. @vadian it is hard to sit in front of the solution and not being able to implement it. never thought that my first project would be so complicated...

Comment: Using my suggestion you basically don't need outlets for the switches.

Comment: now I am totally confused because thats the only way I so far learned how to create buttons and so on that actually work.

Comment: `IBOutlet`s are needed when you want to send information to an UI element. In this case you receive only information from the UI elements by `IBAction`. You're be able to distinguish the switches by the different tags. The tag is also the index to the position in the two arrays. It's just a suggestion. There are other ways to accomplish this task.

Comment: I found it! I now know how to tag inside Interface Builder. The arrays I created are still in the right position aren't they?

Comment: I did everything just like you said until step 4. Please tell me what to do with this `@IBAction func random(sender: AnyObject) {
        
        let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(cocktailfiltered.count)))
        
      ergebnis.text = (cocktailfiltered[randomIndex].name)`

Comment: You have to compose an `NSPredicate` object containing all `true` keys to filter the cocktail array. Please read the `Predicate Programming Guide` how to do that. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/AdditionalChapters/Introduction.html. You can also create a function to return a closure to use the native `filter` function. In any case you need a dynamic expression `filter if orange is true and lemon is true` or if you need also `false` states add them to the expression accordingly.

Comment: I added an example to create the predicate.

Comment: Well thank you very much for your help so far and for your example. I was hoping to understand how to use this right now so I could use the app tonight but it's taking too long for now. Thank you anyways!!

Comment: Keine Ursache und guten Rutsch (you're welcome and happy New Year).

Comment: Ebenso guten Rutsch in die Schweiz (und ins neue Jahr!). Ich stehe mit swift halt wirklich noch am Anfang....

Comment: Ok, after some time and reading lots of posts I still don't get it. Please help me @vadian! I found out that using a NSPredicate in Swift in order to filter an array is not that simple. Finally I came up with this: let filtered = (cocktails as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(predicate)
        let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(filtered.count))) which led my app to crash...

Comment: are you still there? please help me! I am now just not sure if this even works like this in swift. I read so many articles, it's not that I am not trying to understand it on my own but it is my first project, so...

Comment: Yes, I'm here but it is difficult to help having only a few lines of code. We could continue the conversation in a chat.

Comment: Ok. I tried to contact you but I think it is not allowed for me as a new user. Though what I really think may be interesting is, that in order to filter the array using the Predicate I had to insert 'as NSArray' because I found that otherwise NSPredicates won't work in swift. There is not really any thing else to my code. All code you don't see yet is my class containing 833 cocktails... I mananged to tag the switches in UIBuilder. Everything as you suggested. I guess something in the action causes the app to crash...